# Best practices for redux mapStateToProps?

Tags: redux, react-redux

As far as I can tell, `reducers` change the state of the tree, `mapStateToProps` transform the state tree for the UI. However, the boundary is not clear. For instance, consider the example from the "Computing Derived Data" docs (http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html). See below.

My first instinct is to put the calculation of the visible todos *in the reducer* (and not `mapStateToProps`), that is, whenever a todo or the visibility filter changes, update the list of completed or active todos. This has several advantages:

1. No need for `Reselect`
2. Having all the logic in one place helps reduce the learning curve (when onboarding) and probably also makes it easier to test (since the integration tests for mapStateToProps are simpler, if non-existent).

On the other hand, 2) is subjective. So guidance on `mapStateToProps` would be helpful.

```
const getVisibleTodos = (todos, filter) => {
  switch (filter) {
    case 'SHOW_ALL':
      return todos
    case 'SHOW_COMPLETED':
      return todos.filter(t => t.completed)
    case 'SHOW_ACTIVE':
      return todos.filter(t => !t.completed)
  }  
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  todos: getVisibleTodos(state.todos, state.visibilityFilter)
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  onTodoClick: (id) => dispatch(toggleTodo(id))         
})

const VisibleTodoList = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoList)
```

Update in response to @DDS:

> To update multiple interrelated states based on one action means that these states can become out of sync... This could mean the visibleTodoList acquires items that don't exist in the original.

If by multiple interrelated states you mean `visibilityFilter` and `todos`, then as per the redux docs, one idiomatic solution is to refactor the state tree so that they are one state. There are other approaches mentioned in the docs as well. Certainly, as you allude, you now have the burden of ensuring the code to compute the derived state (visible todos) is always called. Once the code base gets large, a custom combineReducer (another idiomatic solution) that does additional transforms before returning the state makes sense.

> Note that the code lives in separate files and the execution order of reducers is not guaranteed. Also, reducers don't normally have access to sibling state meaning they cannot derive data from it

See my comments above.

> The example above may be contrived but the point is that to make the data stable, it's best to have a single source every component can rely on, and this requires the data to be normalized.

Yea, it all comes down to normalized vs denormalized state. I'm not yet convinced that normalized state is *always* the way to go...for the same reason NoSQL databases are *sometimes* the way to go.

> Reasoning about more complex state [normalized and denormalized state] becomes difficult very quickly. This is why it is better to not put derived data in state.

Ah I see your point. Six months from now I may not see that `visibleTodos` is derived state (and so should be treated as readonly). Unexpected things will result.

Comment: What is the best practice for shaping your mapStateToProps? Should it consist of primitive values or ADTs/objects? For example, if I want to access the ID of some object, should I just pass that object or extract the ID out and map its state to props?

Answer (score 3):

NOTE: The are my two cents based on my personal experience, and not necessarily in line with best practices.

#### Redux state

This should be normalised, primarily because it makes writes (inserts/updates/deletes) easy to reason about.
Normalising redux state would mean that you should not be storing derived data in the redux state.

#### Derived data:

My personal experience of using react/redux (before the nice docs on http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html emerged) made me try to follow something that you (OP) are striving for: simplifying the places where code is written.
After accepting the normalization principle, the natural place for me to start writing derivation or 'state view' logic was in the react component's render function (which now sounds a little ugly). As code evolves, the render function becomes neater by creating derivation functions and keeping them outside the react component.

This creates an easy mental model for people working with the codebase:

- redux-state: Normalized store
- mapStateToProps: Just maps state to prop values in a dumb way
- ReactComponent: Contains all the logic to 'view' the right pieces of the state and then render it. Further modularisation done as deemed necessary by author.

Comment: from testing point of view, moving lots of logic to the react component makes for harder testing

Comment: True! The problem then becomes trying to test react-components instead which is painful (although seems to be getting better by the day). I'm trying to look at derived data as if it's a part of the view, in which case, I make it a part of testing react-components. But it keeps reasoning about the state and actions fairly simple. Maybe a hybrid approach? Stuff I want to test, I can keep in mapStateToProps and so on.

Comment: @iamnat `mapStateToProps: Just maps state to prop values in a dumb way`

Can you elaborate more here? What would be a best practice for mapping your state to props?

Answer (score 2):

The reason Reselect is used over putting this in a reducer and in the state is analogous to why React is used instead of jQuery.

To update multiple interrelated states based on one action means that these states can become out of sync. Maybe one reducer interprets `ADD_ITEM` to mean "upsert" when another, coded in a different file months later by someone else, takes it to mean "insert with duplicates allowed". This could mean the `visibleTodoList` acquires items that don't exist in the original.

Note that the code lives in separate files and the execution order of reducers is not guaranteed. Also, reducers don't normally have access to sibling state meaning they cannot derive data from it.

The example above may be contrived but the point is that to make the data stable, it's best to have a single source every component can rely on, and this requires the data to be normalized. Storing derived data means storing the same data in multiple places and forms,  but being interdependent.

Having a single source and having data flow unidirectionally, prevents disagreement on which data is authoritative.

The state should be thought of as clean-room data. It has a number of properties that make it dependable and easy to reason about:

- All state is immutable, which means it can be stored anywhere and treated like a value without fear it will later be modified by external code.
- All state is serializable which guarantees that it contains no code or cycles and can be shipped and stored easily.
- It is normalized so it contains only one copy of each datum. There can be no desynchronisation or disagreement between different parts of the state. This makes the state harder to make internally inconsistent.

Reasoning about more complex state becomes difficult very quickly. This is why it is better to not put derived data in state.

Note that what may seem like a great and simple idea when you code it may trip you up years later when that little side project has blossomed into a highly sought-after essential tool. It's not hard to hack up working code on the first round so doing things the Redux Way is very much a future-proofing strategy.